# How to insert init-data into a table in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I wanted to insert some initial data into the table in hive, so I created below HQL,

```
    INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE table PARTITION(dt='2014-06-26') SELECT 'key_sum' as key, '0' as value;
```

but it does not work.

There is another query like the above,

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE table PARTITION(dt='2014-06-26') SELECT 'key_sum' as key, '0' as value FROM table limit 1;
```

But it also didn't work, as I see that the tables are empty.

How can I set the initial data into the table?
(There is the reason why I have to do self-join)

Answer (score 1):

About first HQL it should have from clause, its missing so HQL failure,

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE table PARTITION(dt='2014-06-26') SELECT 'key_sum' as key, '0' as value;
```

Regarding second HQL, from table should have atleast one row, so it can set the constant init values into your newly created table.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE table PARTITION(dt='2014-06-26') SELECT 'key_sum', '0' FROM table limit 1;
```

you can use any old hive table having data into it, and give a hit.

Answer (score 0):

The following query works fine if we have already test table created in hive.

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE test PARTITION(dt='2014-06-26') SELECT 'key_sum' as key, '0' as value FROM test;

I think the table which we perform insert should be created first.